# Sentiment Analysis -- what does score and comparative work?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

[image]

I am doing sentiment analysis to an article. I don't know how to use sentiment analysis to check whether the article is positive, negative or neutral.

the score is 18. the comparative is 7.7%

Answer (score 1):

Each word detected as "positive" or "negative" in your article has a score (above 0 for positive, below 0 for negative.) Usually some words have more impact than others (so where stupid may be -2 bad may be -3).

The "score" is going to be all your values added up. So if you had words that were -3, +2, +2 your score would be +1. It has no upper or limit bounds because the scores are just added up.

The "comparative" is the sum of the negatives compared to the sum of the positives, so it will range from -100% (completely negative) to 100% (totally positive).

Comment: is the comparative score a number between -1 and 1? Because according to the npm docs for the `sentiment` module it can be between `-5` and `5` .. my scores always come out around .02 or -.02.

Comment: @chovy not sure what they might be indicating about -5 and 5. My understanding matches your experience (that is should be between -1 and 1).